# 'Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined' when using wavesurfer.js with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, wavesurfer.js

I am currently trying to implement [wavesurfer.js](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js) into an Ember.js component. So far I've imported it into my `ember-cli-build.js` file like so:

```
app.import('bower_components/wavesurfer.js/dist/wavesurfer.min.js');
```

And then inside the component's js file I am trying to do a simple test of it by calling it on a div that is included in the helper's template.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didRender() {
        var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
            container: '#waveform',
            waveColor: 'violet',
            progressColor: 'purple',
            barWidth: 3,
            cursorWidth: 3,
            normalize: true
        });
        wavesurfer.load('assets/sound4.mp3');
    }
});
```

Now when the page loads it shows the wavesurfer.js scrollbar but nothing else. In the console it reads `Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined`.

It seems to be erroring at line `2048` of wavesurfer.js with the following errors:

```
entry.start = (entry.waveCtx.canvas.offsetLeft / totalWidth) || 0;


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined
```

**Any** help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely stuck as to what I should do.

Comment: try 1.3.1 or later versions. you might be interested to see this [issue discussion](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/950)

Comment: @kumkanillam thanks, I haven't found that discussion yet. I just tried 1.3.4 and 1.3.1 with no luck but rolling all the way back to 1.2.8 works!